# How can I list directories without including files including dirent.h?

Tags: c, directory, dirent.h

I have searched this a *lot* about this thing: How to make C print all directories *without* dirent.h. I found something called tiny dirent or something but it wasn't so useful for me becasue it had a licence on it. I have found seveal things more that wasn't uselful. Now, I want to do it myself that I found out the only way is to write one by myself. I am using GCC to compile and I use linux to make one. So, how can I make my own dirent.h without including any header files?

Comment: What operating system do you have? If you want to code your own [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) that should be mentioned *explicitly* in your question (which is unclear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is operating system specific, since not all C implementations (think of some C program for [Arduino](https://arduino.cc)) have directories.

> How can I list directories without including files including dirent.h?

By using some other libraries, or directly some [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

Did you consider using [ntfw(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html), or [readdir(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) ?

> So, how can I make my own dirent.h without including any header files?

You create C source files with a good editor such as [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/). Or you use (or write) a program generating some C code (e.g. [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/)).

You should read a good [operating system textbook](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/) if you want to create your own OS. Then see also [OSDEV](https://www.osdev.org/), and budget several years of full time work. See also [LinuxFromScratch](https://linuxfromscratch.org/), and study for inspiration the source code of the Linux [kernel](https://kernel.org/) or of [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/).

> I am using GCC to compile

Be sure to read the documentation of GCC ([user](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/) and [internals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/)). Use it as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. You might code your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/plugins.html), or generate some C code with e.g. [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp)

Comment: Actually, the thing I wnat to do is for preparing to make an operating system which is not based on Linux. But as far as I know, I cannot use syscalls which is a linux function during the development.

Comment: You can create your OS from scratch. You'll need many years for that. Good luck

Comment: Re "*I cannot use syscalls*", You can't read directories (or otherwise access the hardware) without a syscall on Windows or Linux or Macs.

Answer (score 1):

On e.g. Linux the `struct dirent` structure returned by [`readdir`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) have a `d_type` member which you can check for the type `DT_DIR`.

---

If you're writing your own POSIX-like operating system you can decide yourself what members the `dirent` structure contains, like the above mentioned `d_type` member.

You won't be having `opendir`/`readdir`/`closedir` in your kernel, but have to implement such functionality yourself.